# Get all the list of users depending on user role

Tags: c#, asp.net

I rewrote a `ActionResult` method that will output list of users depending if it is a `SuperAdmin`, `OrganisationAdmin` or `GroupAdmin`. I know there is a lot of things in the codes I still can improve so I would ask the community here the things I should learn and keep in mind when writing codes.

You might ask why I have parameters on the method below is because I have a filtering selection in the view for this method which I have to resubmit whenever I have to get a different list from a specific organisation.

Also I changed some names in the codes which is different from the real code that we have.

```
public ActionResult Index(UserManagementViewModel model, int page = 1)
{
    model.CurrentAccountId = CurrentAccount.Id;
    model.IsSuperAdmin = CurrentAccount.HasRole(RoleNames.SuperAdmin);
    model.IsGroupAdmin = CurrentAccount.HasRole(RoleNames.GroupAdmin);
    model.IsOrganisationalAdmin = CurrentAccount.HasRole(RoleNames.OrganisationalAdmin);

    //permission
    if (CurrentOrganisation != null && (model.IsSuperAdmin || model.IsOrganisationalAdmin))
    {
        if(CurrentOrganisation.Permission1)
        {
            model.Permission1 = true;
            //get list of bulk link
            var bulks = _bulkRepository.GetBulkForOrganisation(CurrentOrganisation.Id);
            model.BulkList = Mapper.Map<List<BulkViewModel>>(bulks);
        }

        if (CurrentOrganisation.Permission2)
        {
            model.Permission2 = true;
        }
    }

    if (model.IsSuperAdmin)
    {
        var organisations = _organisationRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(i => i.Name);
        var users = AccountManager.Users.Where(a => !a.Deleted).OrderBy(a => a.LastName);

        var activeUsers = users.Where(u => u.Organisation.IsClient).Paged(page, 20);
        var trialUsers = users.Where(u => !u.Organisation.IsClient).Paged(page, 20);

        var organisationId = model.CurrentOrganisation;
        if (organisationId != 0)
        {

            activeUsers = users.Where(u => u.Organisation.Id == organisationId && u.Organisation.IsClient).Paged(page, 20);
            trialUsers = users.Where(u => u.Organisation.Id == organisationId && !u.Organisation.IsClient).Paged(page, 20);
        }

        var activeUserList = Mapper.Map<List<UserViewModel>>(activeUsers);
        var trialUserList = Mapper.Map<List<UserViewModel>>(trialUsers);

        model.ActiveUserPageList = new PagedList<UserViewModel>(activeUserList, page, 20, c => activeUsers.TotalItemCount);
        model.TrialUserPageList = new PagedList<UserViewModel>(trialUserList, page, 20, c => activeUsers.TotalItemCount);

        model.ClientOrganisationList = organisations.Where(i => i.IsClient).Select(i => 
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.Name,
                Value = i.Id.ToString(),
                Selected = i.Id.ToString() == organisationId.ToString()
            }
        ).ToList();

        model.NonClientOrganisationList = organisations.Where(i => !i.IsClient).Select(i =>
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.Name,
                Value = i.Id.ToString(),
                Selected = i.Id.ToString() == organisationId.ToString()
            }
        ).ToList();

        return View(model); // immediately return the result
    }

    var organisationUsers = AccountManager.Users.Where(u => u.Organisation.Id == CurrentOrganisation.Id 
                                                            && !u.Deleted).OrderBy(a => a.LastName);

    if (model.IsOrganisationalAdmin)
    {
        var users = organisationUsers.Where(u => u.Status == Status.Approved).Paged(page, 20);
        var userrequests = organisationUsers.Where(u => u.Status == Status.Pending).Paged(page, 20);

        //initialize all neccessary properties for IA
        model.OrganisationName = CurrentOrganisation.Name;
        model.UsedAccounts = users.TotalItemCount;
        model.AllowedAccounts = CurrentOrganisation.Licence.AllowedAccounts;

        var userList = Mapper.Map<List<UserViewModel>>(users);
        var userRequestList = Mapper.Map<List<UserViewModel>>(userrequests);

        model.ActiveUserPageList = new PagedList<UserViewModel>(userList, page, 20, c => users.TotalItemCount);
        model.UserRequestPageList = new PagedList<UserViewModel>(userRequestList, page, 20, c => userrequests.TotalItemCount);

        return View(model);
    }

    model.GroupAdmin = new GroupAdmin();
    model.GroupAdmin.CanCreateNewUser = CurrentAccount.CanCreateNewUser;
    model.GroupAdmin.CanViewAllUsers = CurrentAccount.CanviewAllUsers;

    if (model.IsGroupAdmin && CurrentAccount.CanViewAllUsers)
    {
        var users = organisationUsers.Where(u => u.Status == Status.Approved).Paged(page, 20);
        var userList = Mapper.Map<List<UserViewModel>>(users);

        model.ActiveUserPageList = new PagedList<UserViewModel>(userList, page, 20, c => users.TotalItemCount);
    }

    if (model.IsGroupAdmin && !CurrentAccount.CanViewAllUsers)
    {
        var currentAccount = organisationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == CurrentAccount.Id);
        var groupAccountIds = currentAccount.Groups.Where(g => !g.IsSystem)
                                                    .SelectMany(g => g.Accounts)
                                                    .Select(u => u.Id)
                                                    .ToList();

        if(groupAccountIds.Any() && !groupAccountIds.Contains(CurrentAccount.Id))
        {
            groupAccountIds.Add(CurrentAccount.Id);
        }

        var users = organisationUsers.Where(u => groupAccountIds.Contains(u.Id)).Paged(page, 20);
        var userList = Mapper.Map<List<UserViewModel>>(users);

        model.ActiveUserPageList = new PagedList<UserViewModel>(userList, page, 20, c => users.TotalItemCount);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is huge and it does a lot. It is responsible for each type of view. This is too much.

You should refactor it so that each `if` that returns a view is a separate method returning either a `null` or a view so that you can chain them like this:

```
// build the model
model.CurrentAccountId = CurrentAccount.Id;
model.IsSuperAdmin = CurrentAccount.HasRole(RoleNames.SuperAdmin);
model.IsGroupAdmin = CurrentAccount.HasRole(RoleNames.GroupAdmin);
model.IsOrganisationalAdmin = CurrentAccount.HasRole(RoleNames.OrganisationalAdmin);

// prepare other suff...


return
    GetSuperAdminView(model) ??
    GetOrganisationalAdminView(model) ??
    ... other views
    return View(model); // default view
```

The first one that returns a view will be used or otherwise the last default view will be returned.

Comment: You might want to point questions of this nature to the Wikipedia definition of the Single Responsibility Principal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle.

Comment: @pacmaninbw this is a good idea - next time ;-) I really need to create a notebook with such links so that I don't have to google them each time.